# Historico de tablas ASP.NET CORE MVC & SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Quiero realizar un histórico o auditoria en una tabla que tengo en mi DB, he creado un modelo en mi aplicacion que haga referencia a esa tabla. Lo que necesito es poder realizar la función que cada vez que se agregue un nuevo registro, en la base de datos me guarde el usuario y fecha-hora. El usuario únicamente podrá ver los datos para el registro. pero no los campos de CreadoPor y FechaCreacion, estos campos son para fines de auditoria.

Todos los usuarios se loguean con su cuenta de Microsoft, como obtengo ese dato para podes registrarlo en la DB, o como podria realizar esta funcionalidad. Alguna idea?

Modelo

```
public Guid IdDispositivo { get; set; }

public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

public string Nombre { get; set; } = null!;

public string DireccionIp { get; set; } = null!;

public int Puerto { get; set; }

public string Usuario { get; set; } = null!;

public string Clave { get; set; } = null!;

public string TipoUsuario { get; set; } = null!;

public int NoPuerta { get; set; }

public string NoPlan { get; set; } = null!;

public bool Asistencia { get; set; }

public string CreadoPor { get; set; } = null!;
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema, si ya tienes la tabla y ya creaste el modelo, lo único por hacer es guardar los datos

Comment: pero como obtengo el nombre de usuario que realizo los cambios si se autentica con su cuenta de microsoft

Comment: ¿Y en qué parte de tu pregunta proporciona esa información? Corrige tu pregunta y pon los detalles completos

Comment: Ya lo he corregido, pero de igual manera ya había puesto que necesitaba obtener el nombre de usuario y la fecha para la auditoria, si sabes como hacerlo o a alguna idea, seria genial saberlo gracias!

Comment: El usuario no lo tenes en las claims? que modelo de logueo estas usando (ya se que pusiste su cuenta de ms, pero estas usando el modelo standar de asp?)

Comment: Utilizo el esquema de Identity pero los usuarios no se loguean con una cuenta local por asi decirlo, lo hacen por medio de su cuenta de microsoft, el proveedor de Azure AD, entonces estoy tratando la manera de recuperar el usuario, porque he visto ejemplos de como hacerlo pero es recuperando los datos en caso tuviera un modelo para Usuarios Identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que he realizado para solucionar esto que quería implementar.

El modelo que ya habia mostrado arriba es el que sigo utilizando, representa mi tabla en la DB

Posterior a eso cree un controlador y su mantenimiento CRUD

He utilizado la clase IHttpContextAccessor la instancie en mi contextPrincipal para poder utilizarla en esta funcion que tambien le cree dentro de mi contextPrincipal para obtener el usuario

public override async Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is HistoricoGeneral && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

```
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    var entity = (HistoricoGeneral)entry.Entity;
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        entity.FechaCreacion = now;
        entity.CreadoPor = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        entity.FechaModificacion = now;
        entity.ModificadoPor = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    }
}

return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

}